# Order 40 sticks

Tags: code-golf, combinatorics, permutations

We have 40 sticks of same widths but different heights. How many arrangements are there possible to put them next to each other so that when we look from right we see 10 sticks and when we look from left we again see exactly 10 sticks?

For example such an ordering is:[image: An example ordering]

Black sticks are hidden, red sticks are the ones you can see when you look from left, the blue sticks are the ones you can see when you look from right and purple one(i.e. the longest one) is the one that can be see seen from both sides.

As test cases:

- If we had 3 sticks number of orderings to see 2 from left and 2 from right is 2
- If we had 5 sticks number of orderings to see 3 from left and 3 from right is 6
- If we had 10 sticks number of orderings to see 4 from left and 4 from right is 90720

Comment: You might want to avoid questions with a fixed output because the optimal code-golf answer will probably just print the result without calculating it. I'd recommend making the question have a few variable inputs, eg N sticks such that you see K of them from left/right, where N and K are input integers

Comment: If you do change the spec so that programs take in input (I don't see why not - you already have the test cases), you might want to think about whether or not you want to put a time limit on programs.

Comment: "Must use your posted program to calculate the 40/10 case" should be a good enough time limit.

Comment: I can't get over the fact that `10!/40 = 90720`... is that coincidence?

Comment: @Tim Whats the significance of 90720?  Zip code for [Los Alamitos, CA](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Los+Alamitos,+CA+90720/@33.797197,-118.061936,14z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x80dd2ef624e22fd7:0x5d8b3bfd6be2acf4)?

Comment: @DigitalTrauma no, that is the orderings for 10 with 4 from each side.

Answer (score 8):

## PARI/GP, 80

```
f(n,v)=abs(sum(k=1,n-1,binomial(n-1,k)*stirling(k,v-1,1)*stirling(n-k-1,v-1,1)))
```

The number of visible sticks is also called [Skyscraper Numbers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL16/Khovanova/khova6.pdf), after the pencil/grid game. This code is based on (only slightly altered) the formula from [OEIS A218531](https://oeis.org/A218531). I don't know much PARI, but I really don't think there's much to golf out here.

Test cases are all [shown at ideone.com](http://ideone.com/a0kj7g). The result for `f(40,10)` is:

```
192999500979320621703647808413866514749680
```

Comment: There's a nice reason for the formula. The number of permutations with `v` left-visible sticks is the Stirling number `s(n,v)`. If the tallest stick is at position `k`, then the left-visible sticks are that stick and the left-visible sticks in the sub-permutation to the left of `k-1` values left of position `k`. So, to have `v` left-visible sticks and `v` right-visible sticks, one has `s(k,v-1)` choices to permute the left half, `s(n-k-1,v-1)` to permute the right half, and `binomial(n-1,k)` choices to split sticks into the two halves.

Comment: @xnor They give basically that explanation in the linked PDF, but yours is worded much better IMO.

Comment: You can save 11 bytes: `f(n,v,s=stirling)=abs(sum(k=1,n--,binomial(n,k)*s(k,v-1)*s(n-k,v-1)))`. This saves `sterling` to a variable for reuse, leaves off its last argument, since 1 is the default, and subtracts 1 from n once rather than three times.

Answer (score 1):

## Python 3, 259 bytes

Not very happy with this.

```python
import itertools as i
x=input().split()
y,k=x
y=int(y)
c=0
x=list(i.permutations(list(range(1,y+1))))
for s in x:
 t=d=0;l=s[::-1]
 for i in range(y):
  if max(s[:i+1])==s[i]:t+=1
 for i in range(y):
  if max(l[:i+1])==l[i]:d+=1
 if t==d==int(k):c+=1
print(c)
```

Example input and output:

```python
10 4
90720
```

It generates all the possible combinations of the provided range, and then loops through them, checking each number in them to see if it equal to the maximum of the previous numbers. It then does the same backwards, and if the count forwards (t) = the count backwards (d) = the given view number (k) it's a valid one. It adds this to a counter (c) and prints that at the end.

Answer (score 0):

### R, 104

```
function(N,K)sum(sapply(combinat::permn(N),function(x)(z=function(i)sum(cummax(i)==i)==K)(x)&z(rev(x))))
```

De-golfed a little:

```
    function(N,K) {
      all_perm <- combinat::permn(N)
      can_see_K_from_left <- function(i)sum(cummax(i) == i) == K
      can_see_K_from_both <- function(x)can_see_K_from_left(x) &
                                        can_see_K_from_left(rev(x))
      return(sum(sapply(all_perm, can_see_K_from_both)))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth - <strike>38</strike> 36 bytes

Basically a port of the R answer. Pretty slow, can't even complete `10, 4` online.

```
AGHQLlfqhS<bhT@bTUGlf!-,yTy_TH.pr1hG
```

The only things Pyth doesn't have are cummax and the `==` over vectors, but those only took a few bytes to implement.

Explanation and further golfing coming soon.

[Try it here online](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=AGHQLlfqhS%3CbhT%40bTUGlf!-%2CyTy_TH.pr1hG&input=5%2C+3&debug=0).